# What does this raster merging error code mean?

Tags: qgis, raster, dem, merge, mosaic

I was wondering if anyone could help me understand how to solve what this error message means and what I need to change to merge my DTM rasters with an asc extension. I am able to see the individual raster files in QGIS but when I try to merge them it comes up with the following error message:

```
Loading resulting layers The following layers were not correctly generated. 
/private/var/folders/pb/_wxrnycx6fsgqw7ykvg58p7h0000gn/T/processing_RwGYTi/e07237400526498eafe8779729c5337f/OUTPUT.tif
You can check the 'Log Messages Panel' in QGIS main window to find more information about the execution of the algorithm.
```

I am new to QGIS and have only ever worked with ArcGIS.

Below is the entire log in case that helps:

```py
QGIS version: 3.16.1-Hannover 
QGIS code revision: 3ecbe06f78 
Qt version: 5.14.2 
GDAL version: 3.1.2 
GEOS version: 3.8.1-CAPI-1.13.3 
PROJ version: Rel. 6.3.2, May 1st, 2020 

Processing algorithm… 
Algorithm 'Merge' starting… 
Input parameters: { 'DATA_TYPE' : 5, 'EXTRA' : '', 'INPUT' : ['/Users/Imi/Desktop/Dissertation /
Historic_floods/terrain-5-dtm_3834194/sw/SW42NE.asc','/Users/Imi/Desktop/Dissertation /
Historic_floods/terrain-5-dtm_3834194/sw/SW42NW.asc','/Users/Imi/Desktop/Dissertation /
Historic_floods/terrain-5-dtm_3834194/sw/SW43SE.asc','/Users/Imi/Desktop/Dissertation /
Historic_floods/terrain-5-dtm_3834194/sw/SW43SW.asc'],
'NODATA_INPUT' : None, 'NODATA_OUTPUT' : None, 'OPTIONS' : '', 'OUTPUT' : 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT', 'PCT' : False, 'SEPARATE' : False }

GDAL command: gdal_merge.py -ot Float32 -of GTiff -o /private/var/folders/pb/_wxrnycx6fsgqw7ykvg58p7h0000gn/T/processing_RwGYTi/e07237400526498eafe8779729c5337f/OUTPUT.tif
--optfile /private/var/folders/pb/_wxrnycx6fsgqw7ykvg58p7h0000gn/T/processing_RwGYTi/7eb753390ae04047b391bc5bbb016dab/mergeInputFiles.txt
GDAL command output: Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/Volumes/QGIS.app/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/python3.7/site-packages/GDAL-3.1.2-py3.7-macosx-10.13.0-x86_64.egg/osgeo/__init__.py", line 18, in swig_import_helper
return importlib.import_module(mname)

File "/Volumes/QGIS.app/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)

File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in
_find_and_load_unlocked

File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 670, in _load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 583, in module_from_spec
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 1043, in create_module
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in
_call_with_frames_removed

ImportError: dlopen(/Volumes/QGIS.app/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/python3.7/site-packages/GDAL-3.1.2-py3.7-macosx-10.13.0-x86_64.egg/osgeo/_gdal.cpython-37m-darwin.so, 2):
Symbol not found: _curl_mime_addpart

Referenced from: /Volumes/QGIS.app/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/bin/../lib/libgdal.27.dylib

Expected in: /usr/lib/libcurl.4.dylib
in /Volumes/QGIS.app/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/bin/../lib/libgdal.27.dylib

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):

    File "/Volumes/QGIS.app/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/bin/gdal_merge.py", line 4, in <module>
    __import__('pkg_resources').run_script('GDAL==3.1.2', 'gdal_merge.py')
    File "/Volumes/QGIS.app/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 667, in run_script
    self.require(requires)[0].run_script(script_name, ns)
    File "/Volumes/QGIS.app/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1464, in run_script
    exec(code, namespace, namespace)
    File "/Volumes/QGIS.app/QGIS.app/Contents/Resources/python/site-packages/GDAL-3.1.2-py3.7-macosx-10.13.0-x86_64.egg/EGG-INFO/scripts/gdal_merge.py", line 38, in <module>
    from osgeo import gdal
    File "/Volumes/QGIS.app/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/python3.7/site-packages/GDAL-3.1.2-py3.7-macosx-10.13.0-x86_64.egg/osgeo/__init__.py", line 32, in <module>
    _gdal = swig_import_helper()
    File "/Volumes/QGIS.app/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/python3.7/site-packages/GDAL-3.1.2-py3.7-macosx-10.13.0-x86_64.egg/osgeo/__init__.py", line 31, in swig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module('_gdal')
    File "/Volumes/QGIS.app/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)

    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_gdal'

Execution completed in 8.97 seconds Results:
  {'OUTPUT': '/private/var/folders/pb/_wxrnycx6fsgqw7ykvg58p7h0000gn/T/processing_RwGYTi/e07237400526498eafe8779729c5337f/OUTPUT.tif'}

Loading resulting layers The following layers were not correctly generated.
  /private/var/folders/pb/_wxrnycx6fsgqw7ykvg58p7h0000gn/T/processing_RwGYTi/e07237400526498eafe8779729c5337f/OUTPUT.tif
  
  You can check the 'Log Messages Panel' in QGIS main window to find more
  information about the execution of the algorithm.
```

Comment: As a workaround you can try outputing to a file (not a temporary layer)

Comment: @BERA Hi thankyou, yes i tried doing that too but it didn't work either.